# couchbase cluster document not replicating but splitting up

Tags: couchbase

I've set up a couchbase cluster with 2 nodes containing 300k docs on 4 buckets. the option replicas is forced to 1 as there are only 2 machines.

But documents are splitted half in one node half in the other, I need to have double copy of each document so if a node goes down the other one che still supply all data to my app.

Is there a setting I missed in creating the cluster?

can I still set the cluster to replicate all documents?

I hope someone can help.

thanks

PS: I'm using couchbase community 4.5

UPDATE:
I add screenshots of cluster web interface and cbstast output:
the following is the state with one node only
[image: one node only]

next the one with both node up:
[image: both nodes up]

then cbstats results on both node when both are up and running:
[image: node 1]

[image: node 2]

AS you can see with only one node there are half items displayed. Does it mean that the other half resides as replicas but are not shown???
can I still run consistenly my app with only one node???

UPDATE:
I had to click fail-over manually to see replicas become active on the remaining node. As with just two cluster auto fail-over is disabled!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase Server will partition or shard the documents across the two nodes, as you observed.  It will also place replicas on those nodes, based on your one-replica configuration.

To access a replica, you must use one of the [Client SDKs](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/sdk/java/start-using-sdk.html).

For example, this Java code will attempt to retrieve a replica (`getFromReplica("id", ReplicaMode.ALL)`) if the active document retrieval fails (`get("id")`).

```
bucket.async()
    .get("id")
    .onErrorResumeNext(bucket.async().getFromReplica("id", ReplicaMode.ALL))
    .subscribe();
```

The `ReplicaMode.ALL` tells Couchbase to try all nodes with replicas and the active node.

Comment: Hi Jeff, couchbase didn't place replicas as replica configuration is forced to ONE, couchbase doesn't let me increase it. it just says you've not enough nodes for replicas>1

Comment: A replica of one means there are two copies of the document, the active and the replica. How are you determining that there is no replica?  You can use [cbstats](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/cli/cbstats-intro.html) to verify the presence of replicas. For example: `/opt/couchbase/bin/cbstats hostname:11210 all -b bucketName | egrep -i "active_num|replica_num"`.

Comment: if one of the two node is down the web interfeca show me half of the document amount in each bucket. if bucketA has 1000 docs with two node when one is down i can just see 500docs for bucketA. I'm going to try with command line. thanks

Comment: Hi, I added some screenshots and run cbstats. looking at the web interface looks like there are half documents active, while cbstast says 512 active 512 replicas for each node. are replica used when the other node is down? and are not shown in web interface?

Comment: I've found the issue as posted below. thanks Jeff for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So what was happening with only two nodes in the cluster was that auto fail-over didn't start automatically as specified here: 
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/clustersetup/automatic-failover.html

this means data replicas where not activated in the remaining node unless fail-over was triggerd manullay.

The best thing is to have more than TWO nodes in the cluster before going in production.

To be honest I should have ridden documentation very carefully before asking any question.

thanks Jeff Kurtz for your help, you pushed me towards the solution. (the understanding of how couchbase replicas policy works).